# Свежие комментарии в самом верху

Tags: wordpress

Допустим имеется 10 комментариев.
В настройках комментариев выбрана опция:
`Разбивать комментарии верхнего уровня на страницы по 6 штук, по умолчанию отображается первая страница 
Сверху каждой страницы должны располагаться поздние комментарии`
По идее первыми должны отображаться самые новые комментарии.
Но почему-то первые 4 самые новые комментария отображаются на второй странице комментариев, т.е. появляется пагинация комментариев.
Если выбрать опцию отображать `по 8 штук`, то первые два комментария отображаются на второй странице комментариев.
А если выбрать опцию отображать `по 10 штук`, т.е. все имеющиеся комментарии, то порядок комментариев правильный, т.е. сначала идут самые новые комментарии.
Подскажите, как это исправить, т.е. чтобы на первой странице комментариев не пропускались самые новые комментарии?

Comment: Думаю, так потому, что первая страница комментариев - это самые ранние комментарии. Поставьте `по умолчанию отображается *последняя* страница`

Comment: @KAGG Design, проверял уже по разному. Если сделать как Вы пишете, т.е. `по умолчанию отображается *последняя*`, и выбрано `по 6 штук`, то показываются  свежие комментарии, но пагинация сразу на второй странице комментариев, и показывается только 4 комментария.